# FileNames in a DataTable - First Column

Tags: c#, datatable, .net, system.io.directory

Is there a way to get the list of `FileNames` in a `DataTable` without using a `foreach` loop?

```
DataTable dtOutput = new DataTable();
dtOutput.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));
dtOutput.Columns.Add(Col2..., typeof(decimal));
...

foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(txtBoxReadFrom.Text, txtBoxTargetFilter.Text))
{
   dtOutput.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));                
}
progressBar1.Maximum = dtOutput.Rows.Count;
```

Comment: Linq? but then again linq is using foreach loop internally..

Comment: One way or another.. a loop will happen.

Comment: @Sam yes I understand linq uses foreach loop internally but could you write me the code how you would get it using linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq hides the loops from you, it uses them anyway:

```
List<String> allFileNames = dtOutput.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(r => r.Field<string>("FileName"))
     .ToList();
```

But why do you want a list at all when you already have the table which is also an in-memory collection?

If you want to diplays these file-names in another multiline `TextBox` you can use:

```
txtBoxWriteTo.Lines = dtOutput.AsEnumerable()
     .Select(r => r.Field<string>("FileName"))
     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the DataTable object to Enumerable().
2. Apply the select clause with the column name as field name.
3. Cast it to a string array.

   ```
    string[] strSummCities = dtTemp1.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<string>("City")).ToArray<string>();
   ```

Hope this will help t resolve your query.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtension` in order to have the `CopyToDataTable()` for enumerable values, after this you can use:

```
DataTable dtOutput =  
       Directory.EnumerateFiles(txtBoxReadFrom.Text, txtBoxTargetFilter.Text).Select(r =>
                                                      {
                                                       DataRow row = dtOutput.NewRow();
                                                       row["fileName"] = r;
                                                       return row;
                                                      }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but isn’t CopyToDataTable() only available on IEnumerable<T> where T is or derives from DataRow.

Comment: I do get an IOException-The source contains no DataRows.

Comment: it seems that your directory doesn't contain any file that match the filter, check it out

Comment: Thanks @trippino. It works well! Though I dint use it, it was good to know.